# Python multiple string comparisons not working

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. I'm stumped on this last question and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The question is:

> Define a function that determines if an input string is in the form of a web address that begins with "http" and ends in either ".com" ".net" or ".org". If the input string ends with one of these suffixes and starts with "http" the function will return True, otherwise it will return False.

```
def isCommonWebAddressFormat(inputURL):
```

This is what I currently have in my Python code, but it's turning out wrong results when I test it:

```
def isCommonWebAddressFormat(inputURL):
    #return True if inputURL starts with "http" and ends with ".com" ".net" or ".org" and returns False otherwise
    outcome = ""
    if "http" and ".com" in inputURL:
        outcome = True
    elif "http" and ".net" in inputURL:
        outcome = True
    elif "http" and ".org" in inputURL:
        outcome = True
    else:
        outcome = False
    return outcome
```

When I call the function with `"www.google.com"`, the result is `True`, even though it should be `False`.

Comment: Use `endswith` and `startswith` methods of the string to do the checks.

Comment: How do I do this? I really have no experience with this program, I'm in an entry level class and we haven't been taught this in class as ridiculous as it sounds

Comment: Please [edit] your title to reflect the problem you have. This question is useless to anybody else if it cannot be found, and nobody is going to search for "Need help on an easy, but problematic homework issue".

Comment: Don't say `if "http" and ".com" in inputURL`.  You could put parentheses around `"http" and ".com"`, and you would get the same result.  You aren't checking them separately.  Do something more like `if inputURL.startswith("http") and any(inputURL.startswith(ending) for ending in (".com", ".net", ".org")):`

Comment: Also, as harsh as it may sound, we don't care how much time you have for your homework. We care about quality questions. So please explain how your code doesn't produce the result you expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot Zondo, it seems to be working now... is there any reason as to why I was getting a true result using "www.google.com" with my previous code? I thought my logic was correct, but if you see an error in it, besides the fact that it doesnt address the start and end, I'd appreciate it

Comment: In Python, the result of expressions like that will be the last value evaluated.  In the case of `x and y`, if `x` is False, the result is `x`.  Otherwise, the result is `y`.  Therefore, the result of `"http" and ".com"` is `".com"`.  `".com"` is in `"www.google.com"`, so the result is True.

Comment: @Zondo the `in` operator evaluates before the `and`, if you change the `and` to `or` you will se that the result is `http` every time.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: I'm sorry.  I'm not very solid on the operator precedence.

Comment: @Marc: *"is there any reason as to why I was getting a true result using "www.google.com" with my previous code"* This is information you should have posted in the question from the very beginning.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely one of the most common mistakes beginner make, the first thing you need to understand is that all objects can be used in [truth testing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

```
if "http":
    print("it was true!!")
```

then you can consider the order of execution of the conditional you wrote:

```
 if "http" and ".com" in inputURL
```

is equivalent to this:

```
 if ("http") and (".com" in inputURL)
```

so because `"http"` always evaluates as True the second part is the only thing that really contributed (thats why `www.google.com` works) what you want instead is:

```
 if ("http" in inputURL) and (".com" in inputURL):
```

although the `startswith` and `endswith` methods are definitely preferable since it checks only at the beginning and end:

```
 if inputURL.startswith("http") and inputURL.endswith(".com")
```

you can see the documentation on these methods (and everything else in python) with the `help` function:

```
 help(str.startswith)
```

> Help on method_descriptor:
>
> startswith(...)
>      S.startswith(prefix[, start[, end]]) -> bool
>
> Return True if S starts with the specified prefix, False otherwise.
>       With optional start, test S beginning at that position.
>       With optional end, stop comparing S at that position.
>       prefix can also be a tuple of strings to try.

Even for me using `help` is always useful, I only just learned that `startswith` and `endswith` can take a tuple of strings to try:

```
 S.startswith(("a","b","c"))
```

this would return `True` if the string `S` starts with either "a" or "b" or "c", using this you can probably write your function in one line.